# Helen helped Liam become best carpenter north of _?

Tags: word, knowledge

Multiple choice question:

Helen helped Liam become best carpenter north of ____?

- A) Australia
- B) England
- C) France
- D) Iceland

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is:

> **C) France**

Because this phrase is...

> ...a **[mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic)** device to help remember the **elements of the Periodic Table** in order! Their symbols appear at the start of these words...
>
>  **H**elen (Hydrogen)
>  **He**lped (Helium)
>  **Li**am (Lithium)
>  **Be**come (Beryllium)
>  **B**est (Boron)
>  **C**arpenter (Carbon)
>  **N**orth (Nitrogen)
>  **O**f (Oxygen)
>
>  And the next element in the Periodic Table is **Fluorine**, whose symbol is **F**, which begins **F**rance!